# rviz doesn't start when run remotely, throws GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest error

Tags: ros, rviz, virtualbox, nvidia, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is similar to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/10588/rviz-does-not-start-prints-glxunsupportedprivaterequest/), in that when I run rviz, I get the following error:

> Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on
> display "localhost:10.0". The program
> 'rviz' received an X Window System
> error. This probably reflects a bug in
> the program. The error was
> 'GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest'.
> (Details: serial 20 error_code 176
> request_code 154 minor_code 16)

In my case, this happens only when I'm running rviz on my desktop while connected to it remotely, with X forwarding, using `ssh -Y`. When I'm at the desktop in person, rviz works just fine.

A bit more info:

I'm actually connecting to my desktop from an Ubuntu virtual machine running on a Windows laptop (I know, it's horribly baroque, but it's the only way I could get linux running on my company laptop).

This virtual machine doesn't have access to the laptop's graphics card, so it can't run rviz locally. However, I thought that it would still be able to run rviz on a remote machine, since the remote machine would do the rendering, and the laptop would just display the rendered screen images that it receives over X. Was I wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50907/rviz-doesn%27t-start-when-run-remotely,-throws-glxunsupportedprivaterequest-error/) by [SuperElectric](https://answers.ros.org/users/3461/superelectric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The X protocol is based on remote procedure calls to the X server. X forwarding basically just means that instead of sending these commands to a local X server they are piped through a TCP socket and then processed by a local X server to display program windows. Unfortunately, this doesn't really work for OpenGL calls so you cannot run programs that require 3D acceleration using X forwarding. Have a look at [VLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) and [VirtualGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualGL) as alternatives.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-12-25**:
Yup, this is the cause of the problem described by OP. I've had some luck with VirtualGL and TigerVNC in the past, but it was far from easy to set up.